# Xilinx Zynq7k 020 linux, error when compiling u-boot

Tags: xilinx, linux, compiler, soc, zynq

I get the following errors when compiling u-boot (SoC Zynq7k 020)
What I did:

1. `git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git`
2. `cd u-boot-xlnx/`
3. `export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`
4. `export ARCH=arm`
5. `make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig`
6. `export DEVICE_TREE="zynq-zturn"`
7. `make`

The process ended in an error:
`fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory`

Terminal output:

```
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx.git
Cloning into 'u-boot-xlnx'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 775761, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2071/2071), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (868/868), done.
remote: Total 775761 (delta 1400), reused 1728 (delta 1193), pack-reused 773690
Receiving objects: 100% (775761/775761), 179.31 MiB | 9.35 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (636538/636538), done.
Updating files: 100% (17628/17628), done.
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop$ cd u-boot-xlnx/
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ export ARCH=arm
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ make xilinx_zynq_virt_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config
#
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ export DEVICE_TREE="zynq-zturn"
sam@sam-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/u-boot-xlnx$ make
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
  UPD     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk
  GEN     include/autoconf.mk.dep
  CFG     spl/u-boot.cfg
  GEN     spl/include/autoconf.mk
  UPD     include/config/uboot.release
  UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
  UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  UPD     include/generated/dt.h
  CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h
  CC      arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s
  UPD     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/fstree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/data.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/livetree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/treesource.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/checks.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/util.o
  LEX     scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.c
  YACC    scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
  YACC    scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
  HOSTCC  tools/envcrc.o
  WRAP    tools/lib/crc32.c
  HOSTCC  tools/lib/crc32.o
  WRAP    tools/env/embedded.c
  HOSTCC  tools/env/embedded.o
  WRAP    tools/lib/sha1.c
  HOSTCC  tools/lib/sha1.o
  HOSTLD  tools/envcrc
  HOSTCC  tools/gen_eth_addr
  HOSTCC  tools/gen_ethaddr_crc.o
  WRAP    tools/lib/crc8.c
  HOSTCC  tools/lib/crc8.o
  HOSTLD  tools/gen_ethaddr_crc
  HOSTCC  tools/img2srec
  HOSTCC  tools/mkenvimage.o
  HOSTCC  tools/os_support.o
  HOSTLD  tools/mkenvimage
  HOSTCC  tools/aisimage.o
In file included from tools/aisimage.c:9:
include/image.h:1222:12: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 1222 | #  include <openssl/evp.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:112: tools/aisimage.o] Error 1
```

Why does this error occur? I use the standard device_tree (supplied with u-boot).
Maybe I need to install some additional software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this error occur? I use the standard device_tree (supplied
> with u-boot). Maybe I need to install some additional software?

Error is on your terminal output:

```
include/image.h:1222:12: fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
 1222 | #  include <openssl/evp.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~<bre>
```

openssl project is [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl).
Some installation info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016956/how-do-i-install-the-openssl-libraries-on-ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you! That helped me.